# Unformattable object error

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Here is my code:

```
from scrapy import * 
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector 
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class lala(CrawlSpider):
    name="lala"
    start_url=["http://www.lala.net/"]       
    rule = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback='self.parse')] 

    def __init__(self):
        super(lala, self).__init__(self)    
        print "\nworking\n"

    def parse(self,response):        
        print "\n\n Middle \n"  

print "\nend\n"
```

The problem is:

```
UNFORMATTABLE OBJECT WRITTEN TO LOG with fmt '[%(system)s] %(text)s\n', MESSAGE LOST
2013-04-09 13:48:25+0100 UNFORMATTABLE OBJECT WRITTEN TO LOG with fmt '[%(system)s] %(text)s\n', MESSAGE LOST
2013-04-09 13:48:25+0100 UNFORMATTABLE OBJECT WRITTEN TO LOG with fmt '[%(system)s] %(text)s\n', MESSAGE LOST
2013-04-09 13:48:25+0100 UNFORMATTABLE OBJECT WRITTEN TO LOG with fmt '[%(system)s] %(text)s\n', MESSAGE LOST
2013-04-09 13:48:25+0100 UNFORMATTABLE OBJECT WRITTEN TO LOG with fmt '[%(system)s] %(text)s\n', MESSAGE LOST
```

Note that both, `end` and `working` are printed in this case.

If I remove the init then, there is no error but the parse is not being called since the middle msg is not printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do *not* need to pass in `self` when calling the inherited `__init__()` method with `super()`:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(lala, self).__init__()
```

Looking at the [example listed in the documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example), the attribute should be called `rules`, not `rule`:

```
class lala(CrawlSpider):
    name="lala"
    start_url=["http://www.lala.net/"]       
    rules = [
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), follow=True, callback='self.parse')
    ]
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your quick reply. I fixed that and the first problem is solved. I do use init now and the UNFORMATTABLE OBJECT WRITTEN error does not occur any more. However the script still does not call the parse function. I change the name of it to parse_lala just to see whether that was a possible problem but it is not making any difference...

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar enough with Scrapy to be able to point out to you how to use the crawler class you created.

Comment: Hey thanks anyway! I found the mistake! The internet connection was not very stable it kept falling and that caused the problem! I should have smell it earlier:)

Answer (score 1):

The scrapy documentation [explicitly warns against using a CrawlSpider and overridding the parse method](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=crawlspider#crawlspider).

Try renaming your `parse` method to something like `parse_item` and trying again.

Comment: Hey I did that and it did not work!:( The problem was the internet connection which was very unstable and kept dropping. I should have checked it first of all :p Thanks for your time:)